# Visual C++ 2008: adding static libraries as relative address?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm adding the gtest libraries as with an absolute link to the project, but this wouldn't work on somebody else's machine if their source is downloaded elsewhere in the system. Is there a way to link to the .libs with relative address instead of absolute address? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a relative path; they work fine for lib file paths (and lib-folder paths in the project settings).

e.g. Instead of "C:\moo\cow.lib" you might put "..\..\moo\cow.lib" (depending on where you're starting from, of course).

(Edit: Fixed a \ char that got swallowed up.)